# @NamedEntityMap does not seem to work in Wildfly 30.0.x

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to use EntityGraph to avoid using fetch=FetchType.EAGER:

```
    EntityGraph<?> graph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("parent.hierarchy");
    Map<String, Object> hints = new HashMap<>();
    hints.put("jakarta.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);
    return entityManager.find(ParentEntity.class, id, hints); // return everything
```

I expected the find to return all the relationships and my Entity structure look something like this (simplified):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_TABLE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PARENT_TYPE_ID", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@NamedEntityGraph(name="parent.hierarchy",
    attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode(value="children", subgraph="parent.child.hierarchy"),
    },
    subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(
           name = "parent.child.hierarchy",
           attributeNodes = {
               @NamedAttributeNode(value="grandchildren", subgraph = "parent.grandchildren.hierarchy"),
               @NamedAttributeNode("childSubscribers")
           }
       )
       }
)
public abstract class ParentEntity implements Serializable {
    private Long parentTypeId;
    private List<ChildEntity> children;
    
    @Column(name = "PARENT_TYPE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Long getParentTypeId() {
        return parentTypeId;
    }
    public void setParentTypeId(Long parentTypeId) {
        this.parentTypeId = parentTypeId;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ChildEntity.class, orphanRemoval=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="POLICIES_ID")
    public List<ChildEntity> getChilds() {
        return children;
    }
    public void setChilds(List<ChildEntity> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CONCREATE_PARENT_TABLE_A")
@DiscriminatorValue(100L)
public class ConcreateParentAEntity extends ParentEntity {
...
}
@Entity
@Table(name="CONCREATE_PARENT_TABLE_B")
@DiscriminatorValue(101L)
public class ConcreateParentBEntity extends ParentEntity {
...
}


@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD_TABLE")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="CHILD_SUBTYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue("B") // default // #hibernate
public class ChildEntity implements Serializable {
    private Character subtype;
    private List<GrandchildEntity> grandchildren;

    @Column(name="CHILD_SUBTYPE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Character getSubtype() {
        return subtype;
    }
    public void setSubtype(Character subtype) {
        this.subtype = subtype;
    }
    
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=GrandchildEntity.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="CHILD_ID")
    public List<GrandchildEntity> getGrandchildren() {
        return grandchildren;
    }
    public void setGrandchildren(List<GrandchildEntity> grandchildren) {
        this.grandchildren = grandchildren;
    }

...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CONCRETE_CHILD_A")
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CHILD_ID")
public class ConcreteChildAEntity extends ChildEntity {
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CONCRETE_CHILD_B")
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CHILD_ID")
public class ConcreteChildBEntity extends ChildEntity {
...
}
```

But the entity.find() with the entity graph does not seems to be fetching the relations, children and grandchildren! What might be wrong? How might I debug or correct the issue?
Application is running under Wildfly 30.0.0-Final

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Test with:

```
String jpql = "SELECT p FROM ParentEntity p WHERE p.id = :id";
ParentEntity parent = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, ParentEntity.class)
                                   .setParameter("id", id)
                                   .setHint("jakarta.persistence.fetchgraph", graph)
                                   .getSingleResult();
```

See errors or what is it returns and go from there divide and conquer.

Comment: So I'm getting "MultipleBagFetchException" after "MultipleBagFetchException". What gives? I have multiple lists, so I really need to load each one at a time? Then the EntityGraph doesn't appear to help me much when I need to load the entire hierarchy!